# Duas conexão com erro no construtor da classe do Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou precisando utilizar a conexão com dois bancos de dados, utilizo Entity Framework, no `appsettings.json`, eu adicionei desta forma:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "banco1": "caminhobanco1",
    "banco2": "caminhobanco2"
},
```

e na `startup.cs`, eu faço assim:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Configurando o uso da classe de contexto para acesso às 
    // tabelas do ASP.NET Identity Core
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
        (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("banco1")));

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContextBanco2>
        (options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("banco2")));
```

Porém quando adiciono dessa forma, ele me retorna o seguinte erro no `ApplicationDbContext`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The DbContextOptions passed to the ApplicationDbContext constructor must be a DbContextOptions. When registering multiple DbContext types make sure that the constructor for each context type has a DbContextOptions parameter rather than a non-generic DbContextOptions parameter.'

O erro, ele retorna aqui:

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
}
```

Porém se eu tiro a linha da startup do banco2, ele funciona normal, inclusive antes de adicionar os dois bancos, funcionava normal. O que estou fazendo de errado ? Existe alguma outra forma, uma forma melhor, ou uma correção para isso ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na injeção de dependência, está havendo um conflito, ele não consegue decidir qual é o `DbContextOptions` que é para instanciar, uma forma fácil de resolver isso é tipar o `DbContextOptions<>` para que o mesmo saiba qual é para ser passado no construtor dessas classes, ***exemplo***:

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) 
    : base(options)
{
}

public ApplicationDbContext2(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext2> options) 
    : base(options)
{
}
```

Nota que a tradução google do trecho do erro significa: `O construtor ApplicationDbContext deve ser um DbContextOptions. Ao registrar vários tipos DbContext, certifique-se de que o construtor de cada tipo de contexto tenha um parâmetro DbContextOptions em vez de um parâmetro DbContextOptions não genérico. '`, no próprio erro está dizendo que é para utilizar o genérico em vez do não genérico, sendo que a classe `DbContextOptions` tem genérico e o não genérico e já foi criado assim para esses casos de conflito de instâncias.

Comment: Achei que isso não ocorreria, pois estavam em pastas diferentes, realmente o erro não ocorreu mais !! Muito Obrigado, estava quebrando a cabeça aqui, pq como estavam em pastas diferentes, achei que não houvesse conflitos.

Comment: Oi @Mariana isso não tem nada a ver com pastas diferentes ou até mesmo `namespace` diferentes, isso é instância iguais e por isso que o genérico ai foi criado para resolver essa parte de instância da referida classe.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação!!!